# How to convert PictureDrawable into ScaleDrawble?

Tags: android

I am trying to scale a picture drwable which I get from [svg-android-library](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/). I can create the drawable but do not get how to scale it.

Here is the code I tried:

```
Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
    int size = 108;
        Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img);
        //resize drawable here according to screen width
        drawable = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, size*2, size*2).getDrawable();
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size*2, size*2);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used

```
Picture picture = svg.getPicture();
```

and then draw it with a new Rect which will stretch it to fit the new Rect

```
canvas.drawPicture(picture, newRect);
```